# How do you insert a tab in a specific place in a tkinter ttk notebook?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I would like to know how you would set a tkinter notebook tab in a specific place. For example, I have this tab that allows you to clone other tabs, but I want it to stay at the end. The code I tried does not seem to work though, as it generates an tkinter.TclError : "Slave index (whatever number) out of bounds".

`

```
from tkinter import *\
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox as msg\
from widgets.translate import Translator\
from widgets.explore import FileExplorer\

root = Tk()\
root.title('Widgets')

tabs = ttk.Notebook(root, width=900, height=350)
tabs.pack(fill='both', expand=1, pady=(5, 0))

tr = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tr_frame = ttk.Frame(tr)
tr_frame.pack(fill=Y)
tabs.add(tr, text='Translator')
    
Translator(tr_frame)

explorers=0
translators=0

def fileexplore_tab(index=2):
    global explorers

    fl_explore = ttk.Frame(tabs)
    tabs.insert(index, fl_explore, text='File Explorer')
    FileExplorer(fl_explore)
    explorers += 1

fileexplore_tab(2)
fileexplore_tab(len(tabs.tabs())-1)

print(len(tabs.tabs()))

root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: It would help if your example didn't use the `widgets` module. It seems unnecessary to reproduce the problem. Also, your code has some odd backslashes at the end of the first few lines.

Comment: The widgets module is for more complex apps that fit into the notebook's frames. Also, you could just ignore the backslashes

Comment: RIght, but the widgets module is absolutely unnecessary to illustrate this problem, and in fact hinders it. Many people might not be willing to install these packages just to run your code.

Answer (score 2):

> How do you insert a tab in a specific place in a tkinter ttk notebook?

The `insert` method allows you to specify an integer id. For example, the following code creates four tabs, then inserts a fifth in the middle.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for color in ("red", "orange", "green", "blue"):
    frame = tk.Frame(notebook, background=color)
    notebook.add(frame, text=color)

extra_frame = tk.Frame(notebook, background="white")
notebook.insert(2, extra_frame, text="white")

root.mainloop()
```

The first argument to `insert` is a numerical index. Tabs are numbered starting with zero, so the position `0` will insert the tab as the first tab.  You can use the string `"end"` to insert the tab at the end.

```
last_frame = tk.Frame(notebook, background="black")
notebook.insert("end", last_frame, text="black")
```

The index must not be greater than the number of tabs.

Instead of a number, you can also specify a specific tab. For example, given the `last_frame` example from above, a tab can be inserted immediately before it by using `last_frame` instead of the integer position.

```
new_frame = tk.Frame(notebook, background='bisque')
notebook.insert(last_frame, new_frame, text="bisque")
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!